# React how to solve a memory leak

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
>   cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
>   function.

This is being caused by the following hooks based component

```
import { animated, config, useTransition } from 'react-spring'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const ProductImage = styled(animated.div)`
  background: ${({ colour }) => colour} url(${({ image }) => image}) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`

interface Props {
  images: string[]
  colour?: string
}

const Gallery = ({ images, colour }: Props) => {
  const [index, set] = useState(0)
  const transitions = useTransition(images[index], image => image, {
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    config: config.molasses
  })
  useEffect(() => void setInterval(() => set(state => (state + 1) % images.length), 5000), [])
  return (
    <>
      {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
        <ProductImage key={key} image={item} style={props} colour={colour} />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Gallery
```

I think that the `set()` method is being called after leaving the page. Normally I would handle this inside a `componentDidUnmount()` method, where I could set some flag to stop the call. I am unsure what to do when using hooks. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is this effect:

```
useEffect(() => void setInterval(() => set(state => (state + 1) % images.length), 5000), [])
```

This starts an interval that never ends.  You need to tell `useEffect` how to cleanup your effect by returning a cleanup function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const id = setInterval(() => set(state => (state + 1) % images.length, 5000)

  // return cleanup method
  return () => clearInterval(id);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I'm not too familiar with hooks yet. This is very helpful.